# Can we switch os without actually shutting down the system

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system

So something that came to notice was when the laptop was at 5% and it went off, But when it was turnt on again after being plugged in , it displayed the OS choosing screen (its a dual booted system with linux and windows). And when windows was chosen it opened the exact place it went off at without any signs of actually shutting down. A computer undergrad here who was curious as to how this was possible. This doubt arised as I had always thought that the system had to be turned off in order to switch between Operating systems, as far as the knowldege I have about operating systems and bootstrap goes. Any references that can give an insight onto this will help too.

Comment: start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_(computing)

Comment: oh so when the laptop runs out of charge, it goes into hibernation mode?